# Can I take motion sickness drugs with me that contain dimenhydratine, or can it be bought at the destination?

Tags: health, legal, georgia-country

I have moderate motion sickness, especially in non-climatised buses, and the drugs that are working very well for me are those containing **dimenhydratine**.

Is this substance legal in Georgia? Can I take aboard a plane drugs such as [Aviomarin](http://www.drugs.com/international/aviomarin.html)? And can similar motion sickness drugs be bought when I get to Georgia (Tbilisi and other big cities)?

Comment: While many medicines seemed much more trivial to obtain in Tbilisi than in my home country of Australia, I found that I couldn't get anything like Sudafed. This could be due to their massive effort to clean up after the chaotic 1990s where anything vaguely considered a "drug" is now a very strict no-no. So it could go either way. Most medicines in Georgia right now seem to originate in Turkey or Ukraine (possibly also Russia but there's some kind of political blockade) so if those countries make an equivalent there's a better chance you can get it.

Comment: I believe that (some versions of) Sudafed contain an ingredient which can be used in making amphetamines and/or other drugs of abuse.  I've never heard this to be the case with dimenhydratine or any other antihistamine, so I wouldn't really expect it to be treated similarly.

Answer (score 4):

I have Aviomarine in my carry-on package with was deeply checked by security officers and it was no problem (the electronic parts - batteries etc. raised their attention).

I can also add from my experience that this drug is a must-have when you have locomotion sickness, because flight is much much worse that bus.

But on the other side:
http://georgia.visahq.com/customs/

> All personal medicines being imported into the country should be
>   accompanied with a doctor’s statement to avoid being detained by the
>   customs authorities.

So, literally reading, any medicines require doctor's statements, in practice low amount of common medicines are tolerated, but for security reason it is very good idea to go to get doctor's statements first.